# I couldn't find the solution on "IndentationError"

Tags: function

```
def duty2():

    numbers = []
    while True:
        a = Input('Enter a new number, 0 to end: ')
        if a == 0:
            break
         numbers.append(a)

    if  len(numbers)!=0:

         sums = 0
         for i in numbers:
            sums = sums + i

         average = float(sums) / len(numbers)
         print "The average of %s is %.2f" % (numbers, average)
    else:
         print "There is nothing to calculate."
```

*I'm new at coding, I could'n solve the problem please help*
   **I am getting this error " IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level* 
**

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space in front of the line that reads `numbers.append(a)`

When you run the code (I've thrown it into the file `tmp.py`), it'll tell you exactly which line is causing the issue. For example, when I run your code I get the following:

```
  File "tmp.py", line 8
    numbers.append(a)
                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

This tells me there is an indentation error, that it's on line 8 and it even tells me exactly which line is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you but I dont see any extra space, even there is ; I tried to delete and run it still didnt work